# ProcessThread Name

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm working on a C# application and i'm facing some threads issues.
I would like to know which threads are running in my application.

I use the code bellow :

```
foreach (ProcessThread s in Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads)
{
  try
  {
    int l_iTest = 0;
    //(Thread) s.name
    //l_liTest += s.Id + ";"; <-- name of the ProcessThread ?
  }
  catch
  {
     // Some stuff
  }}
```

My point is, I would like to know which class or assambly has launched my thread.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: You can't go back from a ProcessThread to a Thread.  Pass an argument if you need to know anything about the code that started the thread.

Comment: @HansPassant: are you sure there isn't a way to go from the ProcessThread.Id to a Thread object? That would solve his problems and mines too.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825882/getting-list-of-currently-active-managed-threads-in-c-net/1827802#1827802) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1825882/3312) and see if a variant might be able to help you (i.e. your thread would have access to the global repository of known threads within the app).

Comment: As I understand, that code supposes to use the class to launch the thread whose name one wants to know? That definitely not a solution, e.g. I am using a background worker `RunWorkerAsync`, and I need to find that thread id by its name.

Comment: @Hi-Angel you should then open up a question with those details to get appropriate research and an answer.

Comment: Thanks. It's been 6 years, I don't do C# these days, so I don't think I'm gonna need a solution. But in retrospective, the comment is apparently about a usecase that the question might include, however the answer does not cover. So, someone acknowledgeable might stumble upon this comment and write another answer here, which would cover such usecase.