# WPF in C# interactive (csi.exe)

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-interactive, csi

I've started to play with c# interactive. In Visual Studio I was able to create some window with following code:

```
#r "PresentationFramework"
using System.Windows;
var w = new Window();
w.Show();
```

However due to [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329978/the-calling-thread-must-be-sta-because-many-ui-components-require-this) using csi.exe I had to do something like this to see a window (I've run executable from net.compiler nuget package, tools directory):

```
#r "PresentationFramework"
using System.Windows;
using System.Threading;
var t = new Thread(()=>{var w = new Window(); w.Show(); Thread.Sleep(2000);});
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
t.Start();
```

The window is displayed while the thread is running but I'm not sure how I could achieve behavior similar to this inside VS C# interactive view.

Answer (score 1):

[Edited]

Hi Paweł,

Here is an answer (tested in csi this time), based on: [Launching a WPF Window in a Separate Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297133/launching-a-wpf-window-in-a-separate-thread)

```
#r "PresentationFramework"
#r "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading"

using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows;
using System.Threading;

var newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    var tempWindow = new Window();
    var t = new TextBox() {Text = "test"};
    tempWindow.Content = t;
    tempWindow.Show();
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
}));


newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
newWindowThread.Start();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but in *VS* everything is as I expect. I want to get the same behavior when using *csi.exe* in console. In *csi* the first piece of code does not work but the same code works in *VS*

Comment: By the way, a better title for this question would be 'WPF in csi.exe'

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the may problem stays the same - I can't directly call window created in another thread even if I declare window variable outside created thread If I want to modify it I have to write something like this: `win.Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>{win.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;});` And I thought `csi` stands for **C** **S**harp **I**nteractive and VS has only a view of it. Is't it?

Comment: Obviously csi and C# Interactive differ in the main thread type. In csi it's MTA, and C# Interactive it's STA. It should be possible to execute the above script and switch context to the new STA thread, though.