# How can I kill all active threads excluding the main thread with c#?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting list of currently active managed threads in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825882/getting-list-of-currently-active-managed-threads-in-net)

In a c# method I start several threads simultaneously with the following construct:

```
new Thread(() =>
{
    Application.Run(...);
}).Start();
```

How can I get the list of all active threads afterwards and kill them all excluding the main thread?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825882/getting-list-of-currently-active-managed-threads-in-net so you can handle rest

Comment: Seeing this is real code smell...are you sure you want to have multiple UI threads?

Comment: @HansPassant so do i have delete my comment after your edit? :)

Comment: Not sure, it was meant to be constructive, not funny ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to *kill* the thread, capture the return value from new Thread() and call myThread.Abort()

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(() =>
{
    Application.Run(...);
}).Start();

// ...

myThread.Abort();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.abort.aspx

However it is preferable to end the thread cooperatively.

If you do not want to capture the thread and track it yourself, you will probably have to use the Profiling/Debugging API to enumerate threads in your process

[How can I enumerate all managed threads in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466799/how-can-i-enumerate-all-managed-threads-in-c)

To learn more about cooperative threading, and about threading in general, I suggest the excellent article

http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: This helped a lot, thanks. I wanted to, but couldn't give any points as my reputation score is below the required limit 15.