# Monitoring managed threads in .NET

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, clr, performancecounter

Is there a way to monitor processor time of each thread in a WPF application?

I implemented a wrapper as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1827802/4997552) and attempted to cross reference with thread performance counters:

I retrieved the threads for the application using the following performance counters:

```
Thread/<appname>/<thread number>
```

I then tried to match those against the `managedThreadId` of each `Thread`, but the ID does not appear to match the instance number.

Comment: Could you be more specific about how you attempted to "cross reference" and in what way it wasn't successful?

Comment: I elaborated in the question

Comment: The thread number in your performance counter would be the Thread ID allocated by windows. ManagedThreadID is an entirely different value allocated by .NET.

Comment: You could pinvoke GetCurrentThreadId (technically, the CLR is allowed to switch managed threads between OS threads - which would make the result unreliable - but I don't think it currently does so). You would probably be better off just finding a profiler that gives you what you want.